# once again..."$ is not defined" - trying to implement sIFR

Tags: javascript, sifr

my file beginning looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/update.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- sifr -->
<link href="sifr207/sIFR-screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen" />

<script src="sifr207/sifr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function()  
  {  
       if(typeof sIFR == "function")
       {
           sIFR.replaceElement("sifr", named({sFlashSrc: "sIFR-2.0.7/corporateacon-reg.swf", sColor: "#FF0000" , sWmode: "transparent"}));
       };
   });
</script>
<!--  -->
</head>
```

I really do not understand why the '$(document).ready(function()' is not found, because I implement sifr.js BEFORE that call.

Any suggestions?
I would appriciate it, really!

shoutz,
supervision

Comment: 2.0.7? sIFR 3 (r436) is a better version.

Get rid of that `$(document).ready()` wrapper though, sIFR takes care of that itself.

Answer (score 3):

you do not have jQuery.js included in your file!

Since SIFR is a jQuery plugin, you have to load the base library before `sifr.js`.

Try adding `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: +1-1: Right answer, but sIFR is not a jQuery plugin...http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/What+is+sIFR

Comment: oh, didn't know that. I just made a quick google lookup to find the jQuery plugin home (http://jquery.thewikies.com/sifr/) and thought that it must be "some kind of a plugin")

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you didn't include any reference to JQuery before that call, that's why '$' is undefined. Try to add this before:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because sIFR doesn't implement a `$` function. You probably mean to use Prototype.js, jQuery, or some other library that uses that badly named variable.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(callback)` is a method provided by the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library to run `callback` when the document parsing has completed.  It looks like you don't have a script referencing jQuery in your file, so this method is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add jQuery to your head before sifr is loaded.